# How to pass dynamic variables to another form?

Tags: c#, forms, public

I have two Forms Form1 and Form2, both of them are already "connected" with eachother. I am already passing button signals, trackbar values, timer ticks..., between them.

The connections looks like this inside Form1:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 = new Form2(timer1,btnBoost,btnBrake);
        Form2.Show();
    }
```

and inside Form2:

```
public Form2(Timer timer,Button Boost,Button Brake)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer = timer;
        _boost = Boost;
        _brake = Brake;          
    }
```

Now I would like to pass a variable from Form1 which is changing it's value every timertick to Form2, to create a graph.

Inside Form1 it looks like this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

public double ValueThatIWant;

}
```

Way done im giving it a value

```
private void Timer1_Tick1(object sender, EventArgs e){

ValueThatIWant = Math.Sqrt(somevalue.X,somevalue.Y);
}
```

I've already tried to access the variable by calling Form1 from Form2

```
Form1.valueThatIWant
```

but since

```
public double valueThatIWant
```

is declared public, it's value is always 0.

```
private void FillChart()
    {

       this.chart1.Series["Velocity"].Points.AddXY(time,Form1.ValueThatIWant);

    }

//That's the method I've created in Form2 to create a chart.
```

I would like to call the variable from inside(?) the

```
public Form1()
```

method, so that i get the changing value, and not only 0.

Hope that kinda describes my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "is declared public, it's value is always 0." huuum? The access-modifier has absoluteley no effect on the value of the field. Of course you have to assign a value to the field somewhere. However I don´t see any code where you´re doing this.

Comment: We need a [mre] here. We cannot guess what you did, you need to show us.

Comment: Soo I've declared my variable in Form1 as public double ValueThatIWant. Way done i pass this variable a value, every timer tick. Inside Form1 i can work with it just fine, but from Form2 the variable seems to be always 0.

Comment: How did you "connect" your two classes and pass the signals and values to one another? You need the correct instance of your `Form1`. I suppose in your `Form2` you have created a new instance of `Form1`, which is not related to the instance where you set the value. However it´s hard to help yopu any further without seeing how this "connection" looks like.

Comment: made some edits hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need access to the instance where you change the values. In your code `Form2` does not know **anything** about that instance except `btnBoost` and `btnBreak`. You need to provide a reference to your `Form1`-instance to your constructor of `Form2`:

```
public Form2(Timer timer, Form1 f1, Button Boost, Button Brake)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _form1 = f1;
    _timer = timer;
    _boost = Boost;
    _brake = Brake;          
}
```

In your `Form1`-code you now need this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 = new Form2(timer1,this,btnBoost,btnBrake);
    Form2.Show();
}
```

instead of:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 = new Form2(timer1,btnBoost,btnBrake);
    Form2.Show();
}
```

Now you can access `_form1.ValueIWant` within `Form2`.

Furthermore you could also omit the two buttons from the constructor, as they probably are components of `Form1` anyway. In this case you need to make the appropriate fields within `Form1` `public` properties, however:

```
class Form1
{
    public Button BreakButton => btnBreak;
}
```

in which way you can now use `_form1.BreakButton`.

Comment: Oh ok, I get the problem. I've done as you said and created a private Form1 f1  in Form2 and furthermore provided a reference _form1 = f1. But I'm not sure how to proceed in Form1? Would be glad if you could help...

Comment: @HannesHauser I don´t get what you mean by "proceed further". What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Inside my method Form1_Load I've written Form2 = new Form2(timer1,btnBoost,btnBrake).  Visual studio ask me for an argument that matches Form1 f1... Hope you get what i mean!

Comment: Hell yes it works!! You're a life saver. Also  _form1.Button works too! Great thank you very much.

Comment: Hey, i have a follow-up question! I would like to pass on a class of form1 to form2. I've tried it with this.ClassWhatever but it doens't work. If you could help me again that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @HannesHauser That´s going to be far too broad for this question. Apart from this you should read some basics (e.g. a tutorial) about object-oriented programming to understand the difference between classes, instances, and how to pass them to one another. And last: "doesn´t work" is **very** unspecific and thus a bad term here on SO.